How to extract the body of a pdf?
I want to extract the body of a pdf. By body I mean the file format that a pdf parser/reader uses to render the pdf. Any language would work, but if you could tell me how to do it in python or Java, that will be most appreciated.
I have used pypdf and pdfplumber, which will give me the text, images, font information, etc. but ideally I do not want processed information, I want the entire information so I could process it. Working knowledge of how these modules (pypdf, pdfplumber) actually operate would also be helpful.

"I want to extract the body of a pdf. By body I mean the file format that a pdf parser/reader uses to render the pdf." - Hhmmm, the file format that a pdf parser/reader uses to render the pdf is called PDF, so your body of a pdf is the PDF file in question itself, isn't it?

PDFs itself basically consist of a series of standalone objects which are referenced by other objects, initialized by a trailer dictionary. The body is more or less the complete file. I suggest you to familiarize yourself with the corresponding standard or introductory lecture and get a feeling of it by looking at real PDF files (using Apache PdfBox Debugger for example). Libraries might provide some insights (like raw content streams in pypdf), but usually have some workaround for common standard violations as well which might confuse you.

To get a feeling, without learning the byte-by-byte details, you can run
cpdf -output-json in.pdf -o out.json
Or, if you want the page data parsed too:
cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams in.pdf -o out.json
Then, you can run
cpdf -j out.json -o out.pdf
once you have modified the data, to reconstruct a PDF.
Java and Python interfaces available, and it's under an open license these days.
Caveats: this is a representation of the graph of PDF objects once read and does not, for example, reflect encryption, multiple PDF revisions, or specific file layout.

As mentioned in comments the body of a PDF is the pages contents and their supporting objects. As a minimal example take a simple PDF without images or fonts just the page as body contents.

As Binary UTF-16, it might look like this.

If you use any decompressor, such as a reader does. It will become viewable and look like this %PDF program script.
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Length 95>>stream
q
0 1 -1 0 595 0 cm
.94902 .02745 .02745 rg
BT
/F1 10 Tf
36 544 Td
(Please Fill Content)Tj
ET
Q
endstream
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids [4 0 R]>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]/Resources<</Font<</F1 1 0 R>>>>/Rotate 90/Contents 2 0 R/Parent 3 0 R>>endobj
5 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>endobj
6 0 obj<</Producer (PDFdo.com  5.5.6.0)/CreationDate (D:20240814061724+08'00')/ModDate (D:20240814061724+08'00')>>endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000095 00000 n 
0000000236 00000 n 
0000000286 00000 n 
0000000407 00000 n 
0000000449 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 7/Info 6 0 R/Root 5 0 R/ID [<9905AC03CAEEDEEBBAF43FC1B494682E><9905AC03CAEEDEEBBAF43FC1B494682E>]>>
startxref
572
%%EOF

The PDF reader will look at the start of file for version and for any /Linearization. Here there is none, so it starts from the last %%EOF (there can be an unlimited number of %%EOF's) and reads backwards!. The first thing it looks for is the last startxref to be able to read how many objects and then use those cyclic chains in conjunction with other chains. These objects should be considered as circles/cycles as often queried multiple times, hence the original Adobe term "COS" (Carousel Object System) and a roundabout 3 leaf cyclic logo! 
Note they do not need to be in order but it looks for a root (/Root 5 0 R = 0000000407 00000 n ) which is the basic entry point for the primary thread. Then it jumps to position 407 and reads 5 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>endobj, thus it knows all the bodies are listed starting from 0000000236 00000 n which = 3 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids [4 0 R]>>endobj.
So we now know there is Count 1 in total (there could be others nested later but the root said this has one location) and that page is at 0000000286 00000 n which is 4 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]/Resources<</Font<</F1 1 0 R>>>>/Rotate 90/Contents 2 0 R/Parent 3 0 R>>endobj
Now we finally know there is one A4 Landscape page with contents as the one body at 0000000095 00000 n.
So now for the body itself. Another thread will have run to get that font /F1 as Helvetica and loaded the characters to use for display.
The 95 bytes long body stream is
q 0 1 -1 0 595 0 cm .94902 .02745 .02745 rg BT /F1 10 Tf 36 544 Td (Please Fill Content)Tj ET Q
Do not worry for now but the wrapping of q..Q is related to graphic state and in effect here simply resetting to default.
0 1 -1 0 595 0 cm is the current transformation matrix related to correcting for the rotation.
Now we get to what you may consider the body content (just a part of the contents body).
.94902 .02745 .02745 rg presets the pages colour to red sub objects.
Tf 10 /F1 BT (PDFs read backward remember) =
Text font 10 units as /Font Helvetica Begin Text
Place at units across and up like a graph 36 544 the (/Literals) string in ANSI (Please Fill Content)Tj ET and End Text.
So now you know all there is to know about how to write a PDF body as Ansi plain text. UTF-16 will be handled using < \x#### > thus look like <1234>.
